# Symfony2 form: How to render the same element twice in the same view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a controller where I am creating a form witg two dropdown list inside.

When I am rendering my view, I would like to have the same form elements on the top and the bottom of the page. The problem is that the form elemetns (dropdownlists) are displayed only on the top of the page, even if I am asking twig to put them also on the bottom.

Here is what I would like to have:

[image]

The 1 and 2 are the dropdownlists. And I would like to duplicate this on the top and on the bottom of the page.

Any Idea on how can this be done?

The top content and the bottom content, where the two dropdownlists are inside are in a single sseparate twig file (searchPanel.html.twig) and this file is included in the page

```
{% include "MyBundle:Search:searchPanel.html.twig" %}
```

Here is the searchPanel.html.twig

```
<div class="searchPanel">

<form action="{{ path }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    Papers per page
    {{ form_widget(form.papers_per_page, { 'class': 'ppp'}) }}

    / Sort by 
    {{ form_widget(form.sort_by, { 'class': 'sort'}) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    / Papers ({{ papers_number }} results)

 <input type="submit" class="updateSearchResults" value="Update"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Cand you paste the code of searchPanel.html.twig??

Comment: Yes of course, I will do it.

Comment: dont'f forget to add the form as argument '{% include "MyBundle:Search:searchPanel.html.twig"  with {'form' : form} %} It should work

Comment: @JulienRollin, unfortunetly not, it does not work. Still the same problem. :(

Comment: @Milos I got the same problem, the only solution I found is to clone the view element.

Comment: @AhmedSiouani, thank you for your help. How to clone the view element? Do you (in my case) to create 4 dropdownlists and put two on the top and two on the bottom?

Comment: @Milos [Object Cloning](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) It's the only solution I found at that time, If someone else has a much better one ...

Comment: @AhmedSiouani, but where to use the object cloning? The problem arrives on the twig side I think, no?

Comment: weird, i use it.. (v2.2.x)  Which version of symfony2 are you using ?

Comment: @JulienRollin, I am using the v2.0

Comment: see @mahok response, the form generates same ids for fields, i used custom render to avoid duplicated id on the same page

Comment: @JulienRollin, yes I sow. But how to use custom renders? As described by mahok ?

Comment: you can use `{{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}`  like described there [form_customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#using-form-variables)  or  use classic html tags without symfony rendering..

Comment: @JulienRollin, the problem with custom render in my case is that I have to render twice the same search panel, so even if I will customize my form elemetns, they will be the same with the same ID i supose (because I am running in the same problem)

Comment: that why add a prefix  (ex: 'top' and 'bottom') to your widget class/id. You could call `'{% include "MyBundle:Search:searchPanel.html.twig" with {'form' : form, 'prefix': 'top' } %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problem in your approach is that Symfony's Form-component will render the form elements with id's which would be duplicated if you rendered the same form twice on your page. You might also run in trouble with the csrf_token. The gist being that forms are not intended to be duplicated.

Here is what I would do. Create a twig-template containing your paginator form without using Symfony\Form, i.e. create all form elements statically and pass it the paginator-object (or array) to get the data instead of using `form_widget()`. Something like this:

```
<form action="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}" method="POST">
    <select name="paginator[per_page]">
        {% for per_page in paginator.papers_per_page %}
        <option value=""{{ per_page }}">{{ per_page }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

The form action will automatically submit the data to your current route, so you can embed it in different actions and it will submit the data to the same action. On POST you can just create a paginator-object with the post-data and then add it as the form's data. After that you just use isValid() as usual.

In your controller you can get the data like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// ...

public function PaperController()
{
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $data = $request->request->get('paginator');
            $paginator = new Paginator($data);

            $form = new PaginatorFormType();
            $form->setData($paginator);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily embed the form in your view like this:

```
{{ include 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:paginator.html.twig' with { 'paginator': paginator } }}
```

Basically you just use the Form-component in your controller for validation purposes. If you want to set some default values or add additional arguments you might want to create a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) from that template, but for your use case this should suffice. Maybe someone else has a better solution but this is how I went with a similar problem in one of my projects.

Comment: thank you. So, instead using the classic form, i will have to create the form manually (staticaly) in the template? I will try this approach and come back to you if i need more help.

Comment: Basically, yes. Again, there may be other ways to do this possibly reusing the form-component. But this approach works quite well for me and is actually easily reusable, e.g. when you have multiple actions which require pagination. P.S.: If you want to set page number or items_per_page via URL-parameters you can do something like this: `{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({ 'page_number': paginator.current_page + 1 })) }}`

Comment: I am trying to make your solution working in my example. I have now the manual form in my searchPanel template. How can I get the data onSubmit in my controller?

Comment: @Milos I updated my answer with an exemplary listing for your controller. Also look for the form-example, you want to use the array-notation similar to how the form component does. If you are not sure what I mean check the html from the forms generated via Symfony\Component\Form. You might want to manually add each property to the paginator instead of passing the array to the constructor or just use the array in the form and skip the paginator altogether; it's just a basic example to get you started. Feel free to ask for more details if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well now. Last question, do you know if there is a "nice" vay in twig to set the default selected item of my dropdown list. I know that I can check fith if and then set manually the default selected item, but there are maybe some other solutions to set the default selected element in one line.

Comment: I set the selected value just like you described. I am not aware of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

another option is user the render twig helper. That way is is possible render the same form in the page as many time as you want. A difference is that using this helper, is also necessary to treat the form renderization as an independent controller Action namely:
in every place in your twig template you want to render the form in the helper to invoke the form there's must be something like this:

```
{{ render(controller('BundleNameBundle:Controller:Action', {
    'param': paramId
})) }}
```

Thereafter is just a matter of creating the controller...

Comment: It's a heavier since twig compiles the templates needed to render every time render is called (dynamic result), but that's also true for massive renderizations so in this case, this can be negligible

Answer (score 0):

Another option is in the controller to create 2 forms:

```
 //first form
 $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), ...);

 //second form: must have different form name that default,
 //to render in twig the fields with different ids
 $formType = new MyFormType();
 $formType->setName('second_form_name');
 $formSecond = $this->createForm($formType, ...);
```

Send both when rendering the twig form:

```
return $this->render( ... 
            'form' => $form->createView(), 'formSecond'=>$formSecond->createView()));
```

Then define the second with name as

> formSecond

, and it will conflict with the first.